# Creating a database from scratch for Client Management

Tags: database, database-design, content-management-system

How to create a simple database with Clients' Info (email addresses, phone, affiliation) and different Campaigns’ drive Info (current interests, ongoing research..etc). The database should allow a user to log daily information such as:

- Date of when the client was contacted;
- Date of when the client have contacted me back;
- status of interaction (interested client, not interested, considering it...etc)
- action required on the current status (with automated alerts to prompt and action);
- log date of action taken;
- data analysis to see evolution of ongoing and past  exchange of emails with clients;
- Multiple users using the same database;
- Checking that there are no repeated clients (email ID verification)
- Considering various e-mails addresses for the same person and checking all of them for duplicate contacts purpose;
- importing current database from excel (including duplicates and consider that the same client can be included in different campaigns but never contacted twice in the same here)
- create simple interface to access database and perform all daily actions such as log information, and upload news contacts with themes information for each campaign drive details.

Important: I don't know much about programming and this should be something simple to develop and use. Any ideas?

Comment: dont ask for your homework to do on so

Comment: Because I don't know how to program (but wiling to LEARN by myself) I tried excel. Currently my Data is splited in 12 excel files with data connections in order to cross check duplicated entries and to improve speed due to a large amont of data.

Comment: What is the purpose of your database?  This question may sound stupid, but it isn't.  The more clearly you can answer this question, the better you will be able to answer all the rest of the questions.

Comment: Client data managing and log info about contact exchange.

Comment: Unless you're intent on developing this yourself and time is not a factor, I'd strongly suggest you go with an open source solution like [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org) which I think will be easier for you to learn to at least develop this one solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for more than just a database (E.G., a place to store stuff) and are looking at a solution UI, DB, Reports, etc. Assuming this is correct and that you want to use Microsoft technologies (there are tons of other alternatives Ruby on Rails, Java, PHP, MySql, Mongo, etc.) I would suggest learning about [Nerd Dinner written by Microsoft](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) in ASP.NET MVC3 using SQL Server for the RDBMS as the concept matches **some** of your requirements above.

Comment: yes, definitely I would need an user friendly interface to access my database. Another problem is that it needs to be compatible with MAC and Windows.

Comment: @user1389598 In case if your trying to go front end tools and using MySQL then I highly recommend to go for PHPMyadmin, MySQL Workbench,  SQL Yog, Navicat.  With the mentioned tools you can login easily and do manipulations of your tables and data